# What's more safe in mode "Safer"?

Tags: security

From `about:preferences` in `Security`:

> `Safer`
> Disables website features that are often dangerous, causing some sites to lose functionality.
>
> 1. JavaScript is disabled on non-HTTPS sites.
> 2. Some fonts and math symbols are disabled.
> 3. Audio and video (HTML5 media), and WebGL are click-to-play.

My question is: What, for example, can one do if I have Javascript enabled in an HTTP site? How am I safer with certain fonts and math symbols disabled?

Answer (score 1):

When using HTTP, theoretically anyone could just hack your connection (if you use tor, then the connection between the exit node and the website), and they could inject some malicious javascripts into the webite. So, JavaScript is disabled on insecure HTTP connections, because it might be malicious, and javascript can be verry malicous.

About the fonts: i am not sure, but symbols can track you (like canvas) and even font fingerprinting is real. So by disabling this, you are safer, i guess.